# Filtering in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have the following `NSMutableArray` called `test`.

I wonder how could I able to filter only `comboItemNames` from the following object?

[image]

I could able to write a `for` loop to iterate each `comboItemNames` as follows, but I am looking for better way.

```
NSMutableArray * names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
for (id t in test)
{
    [names addObject:((ComboItemPopOver*)t).comboItemNames];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[test valueForKey:@"comboItemNames"];`